# What's wrong with my code, I tried loading data between 2 datetimepicker using reportviewer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

My error in report viewer keeps saying that

**some parameter or credentials have not been specified** 
[This is the first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO2R4.png)

and after I clicked the load data, report viewer says that

**cannot create a data reader for data set  'LogHistoryDataSet'**
[This is the 2nd error after I click the Load Data button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnHXe.png)

The LogHistoryDataSet is my DataSet for the report and my LogHistory_tbl is my DataTable in LogHistoryDataSet.

```
   Try

        Dim startDateParam As String = startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Dim endDateParam As String = endDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

        Dim reportDataSource As ReportDataSource
        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        With ReportViewer1.LocalReport
            .ReportPath = Application.StartupPath & "\LogHistoryReport.rdlc"
            .DataSources.Clear()
        End With

        Dim dataSet As New LogHistoryDataSet
        Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter

        connection.Open()
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("Select logName, logType, logOperation, logDate from LogHistory_tbl where logDate between @startDateParam and @endDateParam", connection)
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDateParam", startDateParam)
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDateParam", endDateParam)
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet.Tables("LogHistory_tbl"))
        connection.Close()

        reportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("LogHistoryDataSet", dataSet.Tables("LogHistory_tbl"))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource)

    Catch ex As Exception
        connection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: You need to pass the dates as dates not as strings. Correct this: _where logDate between '" & startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & "' and '" & endDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & "'"_. Also, its good practice to use parameters instead of string concatenation. Good luck.

Comment: How about you tell us what the actual error message was, rather than some vague approximation?